# Page views not correctly sized after segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I recently updated my XCode to version 11.0. Ever since the update segues on an old project have been behaving weirdly. When I segue modally to a new page the page does not fill the entire screen and seemingly hovers instead.

Here is a picture of the view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vDcu.jpg

I would like for the pages to take up the full length of the device screen as they did prior to the upgrade.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has to do with the new default modal presentation style in iOS 13.
To set the prior behavior, you need to change the presentation style to full screen.

You can do this both in storyboard by editing your segue's **Presentation** attribute and setting it from **Automatic** to **Full Screen**:

[image]

Alternatively, if you are presenting your View Controller programmatically, you can set your View Controllers `modalPresentationStyle` before presenting it, like so:

```
let detailController = /* your View Controller */
detailController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
present(detailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the solution turned out to be more obvious than I realized. If you click on the segue symbol on the storyboard some options are displayed in the side bar.

Selecting presentation -> full screen from the drop down fixed my issue.

Adding a screenshot for clarity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/knucS.jpg

Hope this helps anyone else having segue problems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically present the controller like in below code :

`let vc = secondStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SearchNavVC")
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`